# Install jQuery plugins in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, timepicker

I need to install [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) timePicker in ember-cli.

I have added library in vendor folder and imports in `Brocfile.js`:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var app = new EmberApp();

app.import('vendor/timePicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js');
app.import('vendor/timePicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

I have created components/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:

```
import Em from "ember";
export default Em.TextField.extend({
  dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
  timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
  stepHour: 1,
  stepMinute: 1,
  stepSecond: 1
});
```

and I need to call this from a template, but I don't know how.

I suppose that the code is something similar to:

```
 {{jquery-ui-timepicker-addon}}
```

but nothing happens.

Could you help me?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the jQuery plugin at the time Ember put the component in the DOM. The hook is called `didInsertElement`

Do it like this:

```
import Em from "ember";
export default Em.TextField.extend({
  setupTimepicker: function() {
    this.$().timepicker({
      dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
      stepHour: 1,
      stepMinute: 1,
      stepSecond: 1
    )}
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

An explanation of `this.$()`:
The `this` refers to the component and the `$()` returns the element as a jQuery object. So `this.$()` means the component as a jQuery object. Once you have a the element as a jQuery object then you can invoke the jQuery plugin. But you need to wait until Ember has added the element to the DOM before you have access to the element.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have test your code (changing  "stepSecond: 1
    )}" by  "stepSecond: 1 }); but nothing happens to click in the input. This is the call in the template: {{jquery-ui-timepicker-addon value=fechadesde class="form-control"}} There is no errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have also include jQueryUI (with datepicker and slider wigits) as it is a timePicker plugin requirement.